# Guidelines for creating a Microsoft Bot Framework State Storage Adapter for a custom database solution

Tags: typescript, redis, botframework, azure-cosmosdb

In the creation of a custom adapter for a said DB that will work correctly with the Microsoft Bot framework I am planning on creating something analogous to the cosmosDBPartitionedStorage class in the bot framework.

From what I see there are 3 operations of read, write, and delete that are inherited/implemented from botbuilder storage.

Is there anything from the database perspective that has to be considered in creating this adapter that isn't apparent from reading through a couple layers of source code.  Such as initialization() for example.  That is cosmos specific and how should I interpret that for the solution I need?

I plan on using 2 databases which of one is redis.  I can test this in an Azure redis instance for my local development and I think that is a good place to get started. So in short, this would be for a redis adapter initially.

---

Update: I went with a Redis only cluster solution and it's solid.  I was not able to achieve the concurrency checking because that would have to be a server side script, which I am using them for my CRUD operations, that will be more involved in a v2 update.

The help @mrichardson gave in the answer below was invaluable to creating your own data store.  I was able to get most of the important base tests working in the unit testing for my TypeScript implementation too!  All but the concurrency test.

In using Redis I was able to create an adapter that is compatible with JSON via the [RedisJson module](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisjson/#building-and-loading-the-module).  This is a Redis module you have to install via your cmd or conf file configuration.

The library I went with was [IORedis from Luin](https://github.com/luin/ioredis) and the learning curve was steep not necessarily his library but the integration with what Redis does along with his library and being a cluster AND using the RedisJson module integration was a nice challenge!

Because of going with the RedisJson module I had to use LUA scripts `load` `EVALSHA` for every CRUD operation that falls back to `EVAL` if the script hasn't been loaded or is missing of any reason.  It also reestablishes the script upon that failure.

I'm not sure if there is a great performance gain for using EVALSHA LUA scripting for just read and write operations but the Redis documentation seems to suggest it does.

> A big advantage of scripting is that it is able to both read and write data with minimal latency, making operations like read, compute, write very fast (pipelining can't help in this scenario since the client needs the reply of the read command before it can call the write command).

However more importantly, the reason why I went with scripting in the first place was more to do with the IORedis client.  It does pipelining but since there isn't native support for RedisJson commands I had to either do a custom script (in IORedis which doesn't allow pipelining but does the evalhas fallback for you) or create my own `EVALSHA` to `EVAL` fallback scenario.

Seems to work pretty awesome!

The codebase is for a RedisCluster and once I am finished putting a few tweaks on it I will post it as a typescript npm package via github and npm.

The inputs also take in a TTL setting which is a good security & performance abstraction for a messaging application such as is the Microsoft bot framework.

Comment: Were you able to get this working with my answer? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I see there are 3 operations of read, write, and delete that are inherited/implemented from botbuilder storage.

Correct. That's all you really need. So long as you can do those successfully, it will work just fine.

> Is there anything from the database perspective that has to be considered in creating this adapter that isn't apparent from reading through a couple layers of source code. Such as initialization() for example. That is cosmos specific and how should I interpret that for the solution I need?

Also correct. That is Cosmos-specific. Basically, it:

1. Creates database if it doesn't exist
2. Stores existing/created database as a property of the class so that when it later checks for the existence of the database, it just looks for the class property and doesn't need to make an HTTP request
3. Locks the class while doing the above to prevent concurrency issues

You would want something like the `initialization()` function if you want to first check that the database exists prior to trying any kind of read/write. It's probably good practice to have something like this to future-proof your bot (if you change/add databases or something), but isn't required.

> this would be for a redis adapter initially.

Unfortunately, we don't have any Redis storage adapters, but here's some additional storage adapters you can look at when you build yours:

- [BF SDK Node Azure Adapters (currently Azure Blob, Cosmos)](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/tree/master/libraries/botbuilder-azure/src)
- [BF Node MemoryStorage](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-core/src/memoryStorage.ts) (don't use in production)
- [BF SDK C# Azure Adapters (currently Azure Blob, Cosmos)](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/tree/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure)
- [BF C# MemoryStorage](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/MemoryStorage.cs) (don't use in production)
- [Community Repo Node Adapters (currently Azure-Table, MongoDb, MS SQL)](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-js#storage)
- [Community Repo C# Adapters (currently Elasticsearch and EntityFramework)](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet#storage)

When writing yours, if you want to make sure it works appropriately, we have a set of Storage Base Tests you can use. Your adapter should pass all of them.

- [Node StorageBaseTests (currently a PR)](https://github.com/mdrichardson/botbuilder-js/blob/storageBaseTests/libraries/botbuilder-core/tests/storageBaseTests.js)
- [Node implementation example (currently a PR)](https://github.com/mdrichardson/botbuilder-js/blob/storageBaseTests/libraries/botbuilder-azure/tests/cosmosDbStorage.test.js)
- [C# StorageBaseTests](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/tests/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Tests/StorageBaseTests.cs)
- [C# implementation example](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/tests/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure.Tests/CosmosDbPartitionStorageTests.cs)

Comment: Awesome. Just one question. And this is related to this question. When looping through a dialog and state is written to the store does it overwrite that users node after every completion. What if I deflect to another dialog and eventually complete a dialog path will that rewrite still occur as to not flood the node

Comment: You should save `DialogState`/`ConversationState` after each turn or else the user won't be able to progress through the dialog steps. There is some state caching done in BotState, however, that make sure it only writes when there are changes. `UserState` is a bit different and you can manually save whenever you want. You could have the branch dialog return a value to the root dialog, and *then* call `saveChanges()` once you have the branch dialog's return value in the root dialog.

Comment: So both saves can happen at the end of the turn.  When the dialogstate is saved is it an overwrite from the previous state?  That is what I am seeing in cosmos.  However, I did have a situation where I think I broke that path and the saves were additive and caused cosmos to break

Comment: @ChristianMatthew Yes, it should overwrite. It may appear additive because the dialog stack will grow, so it basically keeps adding to the dialog stack as more dialogs are started. I can't say that I've seen your broken Cosmos scenario, but if it happens again, open a new question and I can help. Might help to read [Managing State](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

Comment: so what I did, and yes this is probably a separate thread, was did a replacedialog('maindialog') in some downstream dialog which sent it back to the main dialog and repeated it.  The effect worked well and was intended but the dialog state was additively growing (ultimately breaking the db) because it would never overwrite (reset the dialogstate) itself to correct the "new dialog" state upon saving during each "correctly ended" dialog state.

Comment: @ChristianMatthew I *believe* [this is intended behavior](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs/src/dialogContext.ts#L396), although it's tough to tell without a clear example and code to dig through.

Comment: I will try to recreate this issue and repost it.  The effect worked well it was just the state layer was building up until it busted.  But if can get it to work well I have an awesome idea for how to incorporate machine learning into dialog flows.

Comment: QQ, I will include this in the update to my Question... How do you trigger a non * etag?  From this code line here
 `const eTag: string = changes[k].eTag;
            const ac = eTag !== '*' && eTag != null && eTag.length > 0 ? { accessCondition: { type: 'IfMatch', condition: eTag } } : undefined;`

Comment: Would you recommend to implementing a partitioned storage setup with Redis?

Comment: @ChristianMatthew What do you mean by trigger a non * etag? I'm not familiar with Redis, but I'd imagine partition storage is going to be more performant, like it is for Cosmos.

Comment: hey mdrichardson. I am working on this now. There are some important parts I didn't point out that when I update the question and you could update your responses too it would be much more helpful. There are things such as partitioning and id creation and the overwrite strategy that would be important to explain out to fully answer the question.

Comment: Partitioning is likely a good idea. I don't know Redis, but the `CosmosDbPartitionedStorage` examples may help. You may want to review [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-custom-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) for the rest, particularly the etag section, regarding overwrites.

Comment: yes redis is different for sure and that sourcecode will definitely help. I will keep you posted as soon as I am done

Comment: so nice got it working!!! One thing that wasn't straight forward was the StoreItems object. `if (documentStoreItem) {
                    storeItems[documentStoreItem.realId] = documentStoreItem.document;
                    // storeItems[documentStoreItem.realId].eTag = documentStoreItem._etag;
                }` couple things about this are 1. how is it used and 2. the etag coming from the database... my redis adapter isn't giving these extra properties in the object. Is that ok and can I just ignore that?

Comment: Howdy, so I had to convert your test over to typescript and well typescript handles a lot of that testing in the form of types!!! However, the core part of the test which is hitting the DB and doing things is working except for one thing.  Updates... However I see your updates in the storagebasetest is based on etags. And this db isn't loading in etags as the cosmos db is.  Is it ok to configure that as such because I am pretty sure updates are occuring but I could be wrong.  wouldn't the key be the better property to check updates with as that is what it is doing in the adapter?

Comment: @ChristianMatthew Regarding your `storeItems` comment...Cosmos creates additional default properties on items like `_etag` and `id`. That code just serializes it into `storeItem` how we want it. Using etags is up to you but definitely a good idea for concurrency. [Read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-custom-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#implementing-etag-support) and implement yourself, if desired.

Comment: Ok how can I force an update?  I think that's the part I am missing

Comment: @ChristianMatthew I'm not sure what you mean by "force an update". If you call `.saveChanges(context, true)`, that "forces" one, regardless if the cached state is equal to the previously saved state, if that's what you mean...

Comment: so I checked the bot against comos azure, in memory, and the new redis data store and they all work exactly the same even when set to true. However, the test for updating store keeps fail specifically at a particular part.  What I discovered is that the test fails for in memory as well so perhaps there is something off or needs updated with that part of the test: ```try {
            updatePocoStoreItem.count = 123;
            await storage.write({ pocoStoreItem: updatePocoStoreItem });
            assert.fail('Should have thrown exception on write with store item because of old eTag');```

Comment: @ChristianMatthew Oh, that's an easy one. You just need to add a check to see if the eTag is old and throw an exception if it is. I don't know how Redis does it, but MemoryStorage just keeps count of what it should be and throws if it's lower than that. None of the tests should fail in the SDK...they run for every PR and we can't commit unless they pass.

Comment: hmmm, first, I don't think i was testing memory correctly, I will adjust for that.  Second, in general I am assigning a UUID for every write and then in the read associated that with the storeItem tag... Analogous to what I am seeing in the cosmos solution.  I am wondering if there is something I am missing for the etags other than that? meaning, the etag is getting assigned on every write so is there anything else I would need to do for that etag?

Comment: @ChristianMatthew You could do like MemoryStorage and just count up. If you want to use UUIDs, you could maybe save each one used to a static hash table. Later, check if it exists and if it does, that indicates its old. That being said, you may want to do something other than etags if Redis uses something else to handle concurrency...I'm sure it does.

Comment: thanks for the input, Where exactly is the "counting up" occurring? Redis is single threaded so in the end it isn't a big deal and I trust the atomicity in that fact.  However, doesn't hurt to be 1000% sure or just incase I want to use another DB later on. Also, I think I am realizing where the confusion is. The write creates a new _etag. All of the time. So if there's a write there is a new etag. Where would there be a check to compare the previous etag for a poco vs pocoStoreItem? Where in read write or delete is that work either done or expected to be done?

Comment: @ChristianMatthew [MemoryStorage increment](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-core/src/memoryStorage.ts#L57). It's not so much about Redis being single-threaded so much as your bot (which is Node, so you're good there). However, if you scale out your bot, you'll definitely need some kind of eTag/concurrency support. The eTag check for Cosmos is done by Cosmos. [Read more here](https://chapsas.com/understanding-optimistic-concurrency-in-cosmos-db/)

Comment: so as long as I can reference the old object etag and compare with the new object etag I should be good? Question is this, how should i reference the old object whether using hash table or increment is that old object what is in the storeItems object or is it another separate object solely used for referencing? I think that is the part I am confused on the most.

Comment: You don't necessarily reference the old object. Just keep a static counter for *all* objects. If your new object has an eTag that is lower than the counter, don't allow it to write. That being said, I really, really recommend against this approach and instead recommend using whatever Redis uses for concurrency. This is getting beyond the scope of our support, though.

Comment: lol I agree and will succumb to what redis is suggesting which is, you are covered because it is single-threaded. But, seems like an interesting problem to solve and the only question I keep wondering is this. If I am keeping a counter for all objects, which I presume is in memory, isn't that also something that shouldn't be done because of scalability concerns.  If you answer yes to that you have answered all of my questions lol. Thanks

Comment: @ChristianMatthew All of you *many* questions ;). But yes, that would cause scalability issues, which is partially why we don't recommend MemoryStorage for production bots...same for using a static counter for concurrency.

Comment: lol I appreciate the many answers. Last comment on this. btw I think my solution is pretty solid so was just going for perfection.  in regards to cosmos for example, I think what you're saying is that cosmos can send an ifMatch qualifier that is done server side to compare the old and the new?  If that's the case I totally understand everything and will bow out?

Comment: @ChristianMatthew Correct. Good luck!